# SQL Conditional Cast VARCHAR for FLOAT

Tags: sql, casting, floating-point, average, varchar

When I run the following query I get error "Cannot cast VARCHAR to FLOAT". The problem is some else on my team designed the DB a while back and put Milliseconds as varchar and sSometime the value isn't there so he put "NA" instead.

Now when I cast the value for Milliseconds to take the AVE(), "NA" cannot be casted. Is there a way to define default value for "NA", like:

```
IF a.Milliseconds == "NA" 
     0
ELSE
     CAST(a.Milliseconds AS FLOAT)



SELECT 
  b.Date, 
  AVG(CAST(a.Milliseconds AS FLOAT)) AS Milliseconds,
FROM Fields a
INNER JOIN Cycles b
ON a.CyclesId = b.Id
GROUP BY b.Date

Sample Data

CyclesId | Milliseconds
1        | 24.1557
2        | 23.4886
3        | NA
```

Comment: If feasible, change the table schema to make Milliseconds a nullable float column, and update apps accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement around your value

```
SELECT 
  b.Date, 
  AVG(CAST(CASE WHEN a.Milliseconds = 'NA' THEN '0' ELSE a.Milliseconds END AS FLOAT)) AS Milliseconds,
FROM Fields a
INNER JOIN Cycles b
    ON a.CyclesId = b.Id
GROUP BY b.Date
```

If you want the `NA` values excluded all together then you will do the following:

```
SELECT 
  b.Date, 
  AVG(CAST(a.Milliseconds AS FLOAT)) AS Milliseconds,
FROM Fields a
INNER JOIN Cycles b
    ON a.CyclesId = b.Id
WHERE a.Milliseconds != 'NA'
GROUP BY b.Date
```

see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49a28/4) with Demo

Comment: Can I modify the AVE(24.1557, 23.4886, NA) to be 23.82215 instead of 15.8814333 (which come from taking 0 for 'NA')

Comment: see my edit, you will no longer need the `CASE` and can exclude via a `WHERE` clause

Answer (score -1):

use CASE...  for example...

```
SELECT 
  b.Date, 
  AVG(CAST( (case when a.Milliseconds = 'NA' then 0 else a.Milliseconds end) AS FLOAT)) AS Milliseconds,
FROM Fields a
INNER JOIN Cycles b
ON a.CyclesId = b.Id
GROUP BY b.Date
```

Comment: this will not work unless you place single quotes around the zero